# Question about Flow when handling HOC with React.Abstract<Config, Instance>

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a HOC takes charge to wrapper component with some localization related props, At the same time, I hope this HOC can support `React.createRef()`.

There are some flow errors stuck me when I am trying to implement this feature, I found myself not very understand `React.AbstractComponent<>`, how it can work with HOC props well?

Here is the flow test [link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCgCWBbADtATgFwAQCocBDAZxwCUBTQgY13A2mRwHIMrbmBueH8AVwB2tRNAE4sGQgOKRCWCgB4AwqPCIA5gC4cAbxyIAjAA4B24hMQD1OAL4AaHAElpWKdQoA+ABTwcfnADqkqioFAAmKmiiFAJY2pQ0WAB0AIIARuaStJHoAjFYyqoaDs7mbp7wAJTx7MnpmYk50bEKACQAIojg4IUCauoOeoYmZhZWth4lLuUeur7+1KLmOAKEyBQ4ALzz-v5BhCHhTXmxSWGIxKiyAJ4AcmsbAD6PgcGhEYy5+Umr6zjPLGO+S4PF21FkxFIABVJNJZPIcBQAB7yARhUgJWhJIEtDpdHoqPoaHAAMl0OHAmFghAwYXClHA2gI9nJw1MOEylmsNg8sx0O12HNcWEQ1FeB3eONwm3Fhw+UROWG4At2bDRFAwXkqc0Fupwixc5MpGGptPpFHADiS1rY5gACgxUKQbFtxAALC5JVCO4jcPWCthYPgYMQKfZyqW6a1JW1YB3QJ0utjgTY6Y2mulhBkutmbABEfGIeZwwA8fr1NgFlYFgeDYkxyXTNKzFt6-SmZSEni8Xm9CeIDmT2s2sx8-rDbyOn2auGTqeTLp00b7iZLHgFlUq3GrPHg4JIpAAstdI8jUejyLVsdPFQohsZ2ZzxjydX51BQsFDEFhIBsZVqtlmZhjylZh4GrA1lmPGEpBkOQpwVfJXQkWD4QoLwQJvfItx4fdIRwdoKGQaBERRGILwba9EJaHQX35VULVdSjqDYeCGS1cs-AFeRln-Yc+RVMEllwPRqGDNVcBdZCPWIGMLU43Uui8MSMAk7V6P9AMPzrfVxO+d9P2-X8OME-xK12GwFPgABINU6U1dTTJwWsQxwBRoNhOD5HlL5Ymci1UywGS5PAF1SyrcCeBAHAADEYFgDk3TgRFVMwUg3Q1Cg92E2VJSwvyZQ81D4J8mcknDPLqKVeAgA).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by what you were trying to do with the `WrappedComponent` static property. It seemed unlikely to work and a little confused so I've commented it out. There are a couple changes, but the biggest issue was probably that you aren't actually using the `Translate` component in your original.

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCgCWBbADtATgFwAQCocBDAZxwCUBTQgY13A2mRwHIMrbmBueecAVwB2tRNAE4sGQgOKRCWCgB4AwqPCIA5gC4cAbxyIAjAA4B24hMQD1OAL4AaHAElpWKdQoA+ABTwcfnADqkqioFAAmKmiiFAJY2pQ0WAB0AIIARuaStJHoAjFYyqoaDs7mbp7wAJTx7MnpmYk50bEKACQAIojg4IUCauoOeoYmZhZWth4lLuUeur7+1KLmOAKEyBQ4ALzz-v5BhCHhTXmxSWGIxKiyAJ4AcmsbAD6PgcGhEYy5+Umr6zjPLGO+S4PF21FkxFIABVJNJZPIcBQAB7yARhUgJWhJIEtDpdHoqPoaHAAMl0OHAmFghAwYXClHA2gI9nJw1MOEylmsNg8sx0O12HNcWEQ1FeB3eONwm3Fhw+UROWG4At2bDRFAwXkqc0Fupwixc5MpGGptPpFHADiS1rY5gACgxUKQbFtxAALC5JVCO4jcPWCthYPgYMQKfZyqW6a1JW1YB3QJ0utjgTY6Y2mulhBkutmbABEfGIeZwwA8fr1NgFlYFgeDYkxyXTNKzFranW6vX6g30xnZnPGPKmZSEni8Xm9CeIDmT2s2sx8-oUMKkMjkGybZpbKZ0yZdOmjE8TJY8AsqlW41fBJFIAFlrpHkaj0eRatjPs0CkNe6MMFyJjq-HUCgsChRAsEgDYZS1LZZmYO8pWYeBLyWXA72XOE13lL5YldCQV3hCgvHg99FXPHgr0hHB2goZBoERFEYmfBs3wVfIFB0HkAL8ZNXWY6g2DXBktXLPwBXkZYoNnPkVTBFDyWoYM1VwF1cI9YgYwtETdS6LwFIwJTtX5f1dVrEN9UU74gJAsCIOEmT-ErXYbC0+AAEg1TpTVDPsnBTNDNDYVXeQsI-XyLVTLA1I08AXVLKskJ4EAcAAMRgWAOTdOBEX0zBSDdDUKHgEADWWcNJRI-JXQC-DMKlJIyqOCrYm4IA)